# SharePoint 2007 Date picker issue

Tags: sharepoint-server, custom-list

We have a issue in SharePoint custom list new form.aspx page. We have 2 date fields, it was previously showing calendar icon with the date field but now it is not using calendar icon this the date fields in new and edit form page.

[image]

Comment: What browser are you using ? I had this issue when using IE 9 64 bits.

Comment: Issue with chrome, IR firefox.

Answer (score 0):

For SharePoint 2007, there is limited support using other browsers than IE. Date pickers and Rich Text will not work for IE 7-8 (64 bits) Firefox and Safari. Try using Internet Explorer and everything should work correctly.

Have a look at [Plan browser support](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526(v=office.12).aspx)  for SharePoint 2007.